# debian/rules error "No rule to make target"

Tags: packaging, deb

i'm having some problems creating a .deb file with debuild

before reading some tutorials i managed to make the file but i always get this error:

```
    make: *** No rule to make target «build». Stop.
    dpkg-buildpackage: failure: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
    debuild: fatal error at line 1329:
    dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc -b failed
```

Any help??

This is my debian rules file:

```
    #!/usr/bin/make -f
    # -*- makefile -*-
    # Sample debian/rules that uses debhelper.
    # This file was originally written by Joey Hess and Craig Small.
    # As a special exception, when this file is copied by dh-make into a
    # dh-make output file, you may use that output file without restriction.
    # This special exception was added by Craig Small in version 0.37 of dh-make.

    # Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
    #export DH_VERBOSE=1

    build-stamp: configure-stamp 
        dh_testdir
        touch build-stamp

    clean:
        dh_testdir
        dh_testroot
        rm -f build-stamp configure-stamp
        dh_clean

    install: build
        dh_testdir
        dh_testroot
        dh_clean -k 
        dh_installdirs
        $(MAKE) install DESTDIR=$(CURDIR)/debian/pycounter
        mkdir -p $(CURDIR)/debian/pycounter

        # Copy .py files
        cp pycounter.py $(CURDIR)/debian/pycounter/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/pycounter/pycounter.py
        cp prefs.py $(CURDIR)/debian/pycounter/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/pycounter/prefs.py

        # desktop copyright and others (not complete, check)
        cp extras-pycounter.desktop $(CURDIR)/debian/pycounter/usr/share/applications/extras-pycounter.desktop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, there is no `build` target in your rules file. Your `install` target lists it as a requirement. `debian/rules` files are Makefiles. You might want to read up on those a bit.

But you could simplify this a lot by using the simple helper `dh`. You rules file would look something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
        dh $@

override_dh_auto_install:
    # Copy .py files
    cp pycounter.py $(CURDIR)/debian/pycounter/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/pycounter/pycounter.py
    cp prefs.py $(CURDIR)/debian/pycounter/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/pycounter/prefs.py

    # desktop copyright and others (not complete, check)
    cp extras-pycounter.desktop $(CURDIR)/debian/pycounter/usr/share/applications/extras-pycounter.desktop
    dh_auto_install
```

I'd also suggest looking into using `dh_install` rather than `cp` I.e.:

`dh_install prefs.py /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/pycounter/`

See both the [manpage for the `dh` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dh) and the [manpage for the `dh_install` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dh_install)