# debuild error “*** No rule to make target” where target is blank

Tags: dpkg, debuild, dh-make

We are trying to create a deb package, to install and auto-start a couple of monitoring scripts we have.

Here is the rules file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@ --with=systemd --with=python2

override_dh_installinit:
    dh_systemd_enable -pmonitor --name=monitor monitor.service
    dh_installinit -pmonitor--no-start --noscripts
    dh_systemd_start -pmonitor
```

When building this package, I get the following error from the rules file:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc -ui
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: using a gain-root-command while being root
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package vm-perf-mon
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 2018.07.24.211328
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution RELEASED
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by root <root@034f0c4becfc>
 dpkg-source --before-build debbuild
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
make: 
: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '
'.  Stop.
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean subprocess returned exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1152:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc -ui failed
```

................................................................................
**Issues:**

1. It claims that there is no rule to make a target, but the actual target name is blank.
2. The rules file has *no* targets, except the default `%` as a catch-all, and the over-riden `dh_installinit` target. As far as I know, `%` is supposed to catch all undefined targets, and take care of it<sup>1</sup>.

Since the make target is blank, I'm not even sure where to start. I was wondering if anyone has either faced this before, or has any idea what this is or why this is happening.

I did read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155224/debian-rules-error-no-rule-to-make-target), but in the OPs case there, it specified a target that had no rule.

---

1. https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#defaultrules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the output, I noticed that "No such file or directory" and "No rule to make target" both appear to be a newline character. I managed to replicate similar error output by adding a carriage return to the end of the first line.

You should check that there are not any unusual characters in the debian/rules file.